# How to convert px to dp in margins programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, constants, android-linearlayout

I got stuck in this, I don't know how to convert px to dp in MarginLayout
So this is my main MarginLayout set method

```
public static void setMargins (View v, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    if (v.getLayoutParams() instanceof LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams) {
        LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams p = (LinearLayout.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
        p.setMargins(l, t, r, b);
        v.requestLayout();
     }
}
```

And this is on click listener where the element changes its marginLayout

```
ArrowUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!Switch){
            setMargins(AdditionalOperations, 0, 0, 0, 800);
            Switch = true;
        }
        else{
            setMargins(AdditionalOperations, 0, 0, 0, 715);
            Switch = false;
        }
    }
});
```

My goal is to conver pixels to Dp, and margin it in DP value, not px. I'm really stuck in this and can't get the idea

Comment: I don't know how to insert it in my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiply your pixel values by the device display density.

```
final float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
final int valueInDp = (int)(valueInPixels * density);
```

In your case would be as next:

```
ArrowUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final float density = view.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        if(!Switch){
            setMargins(AdditionalOperations, 0, 0, 0, 800 * density);
            Switch = true;
        }
        else{
            setMargins(AdditionalOperations, 0, 0, 0, 715 * density);
            Switch = false;
       }
   }
});
```

**Tip:** As you are using constant values, you may want to cache them instead of computing the values all the time.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!